# How to access base class constructor when using CRTP

Tags: c++, crtp

I need to insert clone and create member functions to my class hieararchy

```
class Base
{
protected:
    const int x_;
public:
    Base() : x_(0) {}
    Base(int x) : x_(x) {}
};
```

I thought that CRTP could be the way how to save some typing and avoid errors.

```
template <typename Derived>
class CRTP_Iface : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Base *create() const { return new Derived(); }
    virtual Base *clone() const { return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this)); }
};
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to access base class constructor to initialize const members.

```
class D1 : public CRTP_Iface<D1>
{
public:
    D1() : Base() {}
    D1(int x) : Base(x) {}
};

class D2 : public CRTP_Iface<D2>
{
public:
    D2() : x_(0) {}
    D2(int x) : x_(x) {}
};

int main()
{
    D1 a;
    D2 b;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any simple way how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add all needed constructors to `CRTP_Iface`.

```
public:
  CRTP_Iface() : Base() {}
  CRTP_Iface( int x ) : Base(x) {}
```

If using C++11 this gets even easier:

```
public:
  using Base::Base;
```

Then you have:

```
class D1 : public CRTP_Iface<D1>
{
public:
    D1() : CRTP_Iface() {}
    D1(int x) : CRTP_Iface(x) {}
};
```

... which can be nicer written in C++11:

```
class D1 : public CRTP_Iface<D1>
{
public:
  using CRTP_Iface<D1>::CRTP_Iface;
};
```

(not sure if  is needed on either left hand or right hand of ::, AFAIR some complilers like it more strict)

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit the constructors of class `Base` in template `CRTP_Iface<>` and then call its constructor in the derived classes:

```
template <typename Derived>
class CRTP_Iface : public Base
{
protected:
    using Base::Base;

public:
    virtual Base *create() const { return new Derived(); }
    virtual Base *clone() const { return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this)); }
};

class D1 : public CRTP_Iface<D1>
{
public:
    D1() : CRTP_Iface() {}
    D1(int x) : CRTP_Iface(x) {}
};
```

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NAxgMsF2RYMDrgci)

Comment: what will happen in you code if  execute 'D1 a; auto c = a.create(); delete c;' ?

Comment: @FengWang well one should add a virtual destructor for `Base`: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WoxkGgrhoAoAzNOt